# Open source antivirus for Ubuntu better than ClamAV

Tags: 14.04, clamav

I was planning to use ClamAV for my PC. And I am also interested to use GPU to speed up ClamAV. While searching for that, I came across the link

> https://blog.cyren.com/articles/an-un-epiphany-based-on-how-to-use-a-gpu-to-speed-up-clamav-1236.html

Here the person wrote about the negatives of ClamAV when compared to Common AntiVirus engines.

So now i am in a confusion that whether I have to proceed with ClamAV itself or is there any other open source antivirus better than that ClamAV?

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: That post you link is from 2011, I would not put too much stock in that in 2016, the only other one I know of is openAV http://www.openantivirus.org/ but I don't have enough knowledge about it to give a good answer.

Comment: that website is trying to sell you something ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing wrong or bad about clamAV, it is the best open source anti virus and should meet all you needs on Ubuntu, you can get a GUI for it too

```
sudo apt-get install clamtk
```

Are there any other open source anti virus?

Short answer:

> No.

Long anwser:

ClamAV is the only open-source Antivirus engine, all other products, either depend on the presence of ClamAV or are closed-source, even the Openantivirus, mostly depends on clam AV (or another AV), some features work stand -alone.

Comment: Sorry to confuse  you, what exactly arer you about to to confussed? So I and other can improve my anwser futher. This is part of the process. you can upvote it with already acceting this answer and keep it open, for improvent.

Comment: I made the edit myself, see how that is much more complete? You can still have a +1 too.

Comment: I didn't though about the GUI, but that Is a point why anser edits exits, thanks, is a helpful addition.